# File is not reading data when getting data from file using file handling in c++?

Tags: c++, oop, file-handling

I am new in c++ and I am writing data and then reading that data on a specific condition as described in my program but when I try to read data from the file at the line  `s.Sstudent_name==s.name[i]` the condition doesn't match I think i am not reading the data correctly from the file.
How I can solve it can someone please help me?
Thanks

```
//Programme
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;
class student
{

      public:
          string father_name[30];
          int age[30];
          float id_card[50];
          float id_card1[50];
          string adress[500];
          string qualf[50];
          int marks[30];
          int sup_id[30];
          string name[30];
          int a;
          float percent[30];
        string Sstudent_name;
        string father_name1;

        //use constructor
        student()
        {
            name[0]="\nno name";
            father_name[0]="\nno name";
            id_card[0]=0;
            id_card1[0]=0;
            adress[0]="\nno adress";
            qualf[0]="\nno qualifcation";
            marks[0]=0;
            percent[0]=0;

          }

          friend void serch_data();
          void show_data();

          void input_data()
          {

            cout<<"\n\n####################################################################";
            cout<<"\n\n#                                                                  #";
            cout<<"\n\n#                                                                  #";
            cout<<"\n\n#              WELCOME TO THE SUPERIOR UNIVERSITY                  #";                                          
            cout<<"\n\n#                                                                  #";
            cout<<"\n\n#              HOW MANY TIME YOU WANT TO ADD DATA                  #";
            cout<<"\n\n#                                                                  #";
            cout<<"\n\n#####################################################################\n";
            cin>>a;
            for(int i=0 ; i<a ; i++)
            {

                cout<<"\nENTER YOU SUPERIOR ID CARD = ";
                cin>>sup_id[i];

                    cout<<"\nENTER  YOU NAME= ";
                    cin>>name[i];
                    cout<<"\nENTER THE FATHER  NAME = ";
                    cin>>father_name[i];
                    cout<<"\nENTER YOUR ID CARD NUMBER = ";
                    cin>>id_card[i];
                    cout<<"\nENTER  FATHER ID CARD NUMBER = ";
                    cin>>id_card1[i];
                    cout<<"\nPLEASE ENTER HOME ADDRESS = ";
                    cin>>adress[i];
                    cout<<"\nENTER YOUR PRIVEOUS QUALIFICATION = ";
                    cin>>qualf[i];

                    /*
                    if(qualf[i]==inter)
                    {
                        cout<<"\nCongratulation you apply the addmmision";
                      }
                      else()
                      {
                        cout<<"\nyou not regonize";
                      }*/
                    cout<<"\nENTER  YOUR INTER MARKS= ";
                    cin>>marks[i];
                    if(marks[i]>=600)
                    {
                        cout<<"\nCONGRATULATION YOU ARE ELIGIBAL FOE ADDMISSON";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout<<"\nYOU ARE NOT ELIGIBAL";
                    }
                    cout<<"\nENTER YOUR INTER MARKS PERCENTAGE = ";
                    cin>>percent[i];
                    if(percent[i]<60)
                    {
                        cout<<"\nYOU ARE NOT ELIGIBAL FOR THE ADDMISSION";
                    }


            }



    ofstream file1("university.txt",ios::binary|ios::app);


    // writing in file again .....


    for (int k = 0; k < a; k++)
    {

        file1 << sup_id[k]<<" ";


        file1 <<  name[k]<<" ";


        file1 << father_name[k]<<" ";


        file1 << id_card[k]<<"  ";


        file1 << id_card1[k] << " ";


        file1 << adress[k]  << " ";


        file1 << qualf[k] << " ";


        file1 << marks[k] << " ";


        file1 << percent[k]<<endl;
    }

    file1.close();
          }




};
inline void student :: show_data()
{
    for(int i=0 ; i<a ; i++)
    {
        cout<<"\nYOU SUPERIOR ID CARD NUMBER IS: = "<<sup_id[i];
        cout<<"\nYOUE NAME IS: = "<<name[i];
        cout<<"\nYOUE FATHER NAME IS: = "<<father_name[i];
        cout<<"\nYOUR ID CARD NUMBER IS: = "<<id_card[i];
        cout<<"\nFATHER ID CARD NUMBER IS: = "<<id_card1[i];
        cout<<"\nHOME ADDRESS IS: = "<<adress[i];
        cout<<"\nYOUR QUALOFICTION IS: = "<<qualf[i];
        cout<<"\nINTER MARKS IS: = "<<marks[i];
        cout<<"\nINTER MARK PERCENTAGE IS:= "<<percent[i];

    }

}
class student1 : public student
{
    public:
                void serch_data(student1 s)
        {

        ifstream file1("university.txt",ios::binary);

        int i;
        while (!file1.eof())
        { 

            for (int k = 0; k < a; k++)
        { 

        file1 >> sup_id[k];


        file1 >>  name[k];


        file1 >> father_name[k];


        file1 >> id_card[k];


        file1 >> id_card1[k];


        file1 >> adress[k];


        file1 >> qualf[k];


        file1 >> marks[k];


        file1 >> percent[k];

        i++;
    }

    file1.close();

            int z;
            cout<<"\n\n####################################################################";
            cout<<"\n\n#                                                                  #";
            cout<<"\n\n#                                                                  #";
            cout<<"\n\n#              PRESS 1 TO SEARCH DATA BY STUDENT NAME              #";                                          
            cout<<"\n\n#                                                                  #";
            cout<<"\n\n#              PRESS 2TO SEARCH DATA BY STUDENT FATHER NAME        #";
            cout<<"\n\n#                                                                  #";
            cout<<"\n\n#####################################################################\n";
            cin>>z;
            if(z==1)
            {
               cout<<"\nENTER STUDENT NAME = ";
               cin>>s.Sstudent_name;
               for(int i=0 ; i<s.a ; i++)
             {
                   if(s.Sstudent_name==s.name[i])
                 {
        cout<<"\nYOU SUPERIOR ID CARD NUMBER IS: = "<<sup_id[i];
        cout<<"\nYOUE NAME IS: = "<<name[i];
        cout<<"\nYOUE FATHER NAME IS: = "<<father_name[i];
        cout<<"\nYOUR ID CARD NUMBER IS: = "<<id_card[i];
        cout<<"\nFATHER ID CARD NUMBER IS: = "<<id_card1[i];
        cout<<"\nHOME ADDRESS IS: = "<<adress[i];
        cout<<"\nYOUR QUALOFICTION IS: = "<<qualf[i];
        cout<<"\nINTER MARKS IS: = "<<marks[i];
        cout<<"\nINTER MARK PERCENTAGE IS:= "<<percent[i];

                 }
              }  
          }
            else if(z==2)
            {
                cout<<"PLEASE ENTER THE FATHER NAME"<<endl;
                cin>>s.father_name1;
                for(int i=0;i<s.a;i++)
                {
                    if(s.father_name[i]==s.father_name1)
                    {
        cout<<"\nYOU SUPERIOR ID CARD NUMBER IS: = "<<sup_id[i];
        cout<<"\nYOUE NAME IS: = "<<name[i];
        cout<<"\nYOUE FATHER NAME IS: = "<<father_name[i];
        cout<<"\nYOUR ID CARD NUMBER IS: = "<<id_card[i];
        cout<<"\nFATHER ID CARD NUMBER IS: = "<<id_card1[i];
        cout<<"\nHOME ADDRESS IS: = "<<adress[i];
        cout<<"\nYOUR QUALOFICTION IS: = "<<qualf[i];
        cout<<"\nINTER MARKS IS: = "<<marks[i];
        cout<<"\nINTER MARK PERCENTAGE IS:= "<<percent[i];
                    }
                }
            }


        }
    }
};
int main()
{
    student1 st;
    int a;
    cout<<"PRESS 1 TO ADD DATA OR 2 FOR SEARCH DATA"<<endl;
    cin>>a;
    if(a==1)
    {
        st.input_data();
    }
    else if(a==2)

    {
    cout<<"\nSCHOOL DATA";
    st.show_data();
    cout<<"\nPRESENT DATA";
    student1 w=st;
    st.show_data();
    cout<<"\nUNIVERSITY DATA";
    student1 Q=st;
    Q.show_data();
    st.serch_data(st);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Formatted input (`>>`) on a binary stream wont work. Why do you open it in binary mode?

Comment: Try to reduce your program to a [mcve] and post it. It will be easier to diagnose the problem and suggest a resolution.